# How to know when the install of of SQL server 2005 express is complete

Tags: sql-server-2005

A silent install of an instance of SSE 2005 is part of a program update I am building. This update needs to pause until the SSE's install is complete.
I use the shell function (in vb6) to run the sqlexpr32.exe with command line parameters.
This returns a process ID (long before the installation of SSE is complete.)
How can I know when the install is completed so that only then will I try creating a database etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to take the `PID`, convert it to an `HPROCESS` & wait on it.
[Full working example](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/faq/waitforsingleobject2.htm).

The link also has a `GetExitCodeProcess` method that can be used asynchronously.